# should free shipping be disabled when enabling table rates

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shipping-methods, table-rates, free-shipping

I Created a table rate for price vs destination. I had to use table rates because in "City A" the shipping is free , but for rest of the cities in the country can have free shipping only if the cart value is more than 299. But now the issue is when I try to place an order , in the shipping method section of my one page check out, it  displays the error  "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time". I want to know if it  is caused by disabling the free shipping in the backend or is it some problem with my table rate.

```
|Country |Region/State|Zip/Postal Code |Order Subtotal (and above)|Shipping Price
|ARE     |*           |*               |                         0|            12
|ARE     |*           |*               |                       299|            0
|ARE     |AE02        |*               |                         0|            0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we’re going to look at how to set up table rate shipping in Magento, giving you the ability to charge different shipping rates to individual customers based on their location–from the regional all the way down to the postcode level.

Three ways to price shipping:-
One thing to note, before we start, is that there are three main ways of setting up table rates–price vs. destination, weight vs. destination and number of items vs. destination.

Essentially what this means is that you can set cheaper shipping to certain destinations if the cost of the item is high, or if the weight and number of items is low.

Configuring table rate shipping:-
You set table rate shipping inside the System menu accessed via Magento’s backend.

While logged in as admin, navigate to **System > Configuration** and then, in the left menu under **Sales**, select **Shipping Methods**.

reference link:-http://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/

Comment: Hi Ashvin, Thanks for the answer, I just made a slight mistake in not selecting the country from the specific countries tab. Thank you once again for providing me the link